# Issue deploying my Node app to GCP (Google Cloud): Cannot find module and version has no instances

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nestjs, gcloud

**Context:**

I'm having an issue when I deploy my node app to GCP app engine.

The deployment has worked in the past, but I've not touched the code for a few months.

The deployment doesn't error, but when I click on the GCP url I get a 500 server error.

I noticed that after I deployed my version didn't have any instances and I believe it should of had two instances.

**Message:**

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
> complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

I've taken a look at the logs which show the following:

[image]

**Tech Stack**:

NodeJs, NestJs, Express, GCP, Typescript

**Error Message**:

Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/dist/main'

**Here is some more of the logs:**

[image]

I'm not sure if theirs some permissions issue in i am that I need to add.
I did receive an email about moving my app from Container Registry to Artifact Registry.
So I'm not sure if thats effecting it or what I need to do.

**Outcome**:

Ideally like to understand why the server has a 500 error. The log messages are not helpful.

**Dist folder after a nest build command run:**

[image]

**Deployment Steps:**

1. I run npm run set-project:staging to select the correct app engine to deploy to.
2. Then I do nest build.
3. Then I do gcloud app deploy.

**My app.yaml file:**

```
runtime: nodejs16
env: standard
instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS: ''
```

**Package json:**

```
{
  "name": "backend-app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "gcp-build": "",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "local-build": "nest build",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "set-project:staging": "gcloud config set project hidden-staging",
    "deploy:staging": "npm run set-project:staging && npm run local-build && gcloud app deploy",
    "deploy:functions:staging": "firebase use staging && firebase deploy --only functions",
    "gcloud-login": "gcloud auth application-default login"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^6.2.0",
    "@google-cloud/text-to-speech": "^4.0.0",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.0",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^2.0.1",
    "@ntegral/nestjs-sendgrid": "^1.0.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.6.1",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.7",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.10",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.1",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-firebase-jwt": "^1.2.1",
    "pdf-puppeteer": "^1.1.10",
    "puppeteer": "^15.5.0",
    "raygun": "^0.13.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

**project.toml**

```
[[build.env]]
name = "GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS"
value = ""
```

**Current Error:**

[image]

**Seems to only say 2 files for upload in the terminal?**

[image]

**500 error in browser and no instance in version :**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you run `nest build` locally, do you have `dist/main` or `dist/src/main`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel when I run nest build I have a dist folder with main.js in.
I've added the dist folder above for your viewing

Comment: I'm not sure why its looking for workspace/dist/main for my project. Surely it should be dist/main like its been for several months prior

Comment: Can you share the steps you followed for the deployment. Does this work locally? The discontinuation of container registry will not happen until May next year, so I think we can rule this out.

Comment: @MichaelC The app runs fine locally on my mac. I've added the app.yaml file above.
But this app.yaml file deploys and then gives me a 500 error.

Comment: Include your package.json file (at least the scripts section)

Comment: @NoCommandLine package json added

Comment: If you're using build packs, see if you're affected by this [breaking change](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes#April_11_2023). A lot of people have been caught flat-footed by it

Comment: @NoCommandLine thanks for the article - I added to the package json scripts:  "gcp-build": "", and a project.toml file (see above link for more info).

Comment: Do you still get the same error after adding ```"gcp-build": ""``` and running the deploy command?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I added this to scripts: "gcp-build": "", and then updated my app.yaml file to contain the variables (see above) - I still got the 500 error

Comment: @NoCommandLine currently I still get a 500 error. I've updated the yaml, package and error image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command to the package json script:

```
"gcp-build": "nest build"
```

The documentation states to have gcp-build as an empty string.
However, with a nest build we must add nest build inside the empty string.

**Original resource from the chat above:** https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes#April_11_2023

**The app.yaml file:**

```
runtime: nodejs16
env: standard
instance_class: F2
```

Comment: This worked but did take some time for the instance to start e.g. between 2-5 minutes the instance in the version deployed went from 0 to 1